# iText7 pdffhtml license key xml not found

Tags: itext7

We could not found the license key while install itext7.pdffhtml(even installed itext7.licensekey dll) from nuget packetmanager for trial version.

How to get trial version key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The license key is an XML file. You can purchase a license key, or, if you aren't ready to become an iText customer, you can get a trial license here: http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html

Did you already register to get a trial license? If so, which error did you get when loading the license key?

Comment: Thank you. We got a trial version key.